# multiple rails sites pointing to the same database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I want to run two rails websites (homepage and app) on the same database. However, migrations dont work because both websites try to use schema_migrations table at the same time.

Is it possible to override default schema_migrations table name? Any other ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The schema_migrations table name is kept in `ActiveRecord::Migrator.schema_migrations_table_name`, which you *might* me able to override (in environment.rb, initializers, etc.), but I haven't tried this.

On the other hand, if you use unique migration IDs in both application (default in 2.1 onwards, I think), migrations from two applications should work with a single schema_migrations table.

See [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/107-migrations-in-rails-2-1) for more information on how migrations work in Rails 2.1 and up.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Migrator.schema_migrations_table_name seems to be frozen and rails doesnt allow t override it.

Hmm, I'll try to have both apps to write into the same schema_migrations.

Thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when this was added but Rails 4 seems to support it now.

From the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

> config.active_record.schema_migrations_table_name lets you set a string to be used as the name of the schema migrations table.

If you are using a version of Rails where this is not supported then an alternative could be to use table_name_prefix. If you are using this approach, I'd make sure that your version of Rails prefixes schema migrations with table_name_prefix by looking at the source code.